# PHP echo code not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The following is a PHP code trying to print some statement. But all it does is print the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\chat_status.php on line 8

THE CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","hi","hello");
mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);
$check_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$row[studentid]"."to"."$_GET[id]`);
if($check_table!=FALSE)
{
$asd="no suggestion";
echo $asd;
}
else
{
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE email='$_SESSION[user_name]'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$create_table="CREATE TABLE `$row[studentid]"."to"."$_GET[id]`(post_number int not null 
auto_increment,primary key(post_number),data text(20000))";
$result=mysql_query($create_table,$con);
}

?>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting gives your error away

Comment: It's because you have an  unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\chat_status.php on line 8

Comment: Yea, close your double quotes on line 8

Comment: Check that your quotes are paired.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @JakeCataford The culprit is line 5, not 8.

Comment: @joeframbach Yea you're right, I jumped the gun after reading the error. my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line to:

```
$check_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$row[studentid]"."to"."$_GET[id]`");
```

Note the closing `"`.

Also **note** the comment from @jamie0726 (Thanks):

> Please do not use $_GET in your query under any circumstances. That's a severe security mistake (SQL injection, it's very easy to delete your database for example with your code.). You can avoid this easily. Check out

Comment: hours of code gets your brain outta you head i guess! thanks.

Comment: Please do not use $_GET in your query under any circumstances. That's a severe security mistake (SQL injection, it's very easy to delete your database for example with your code.). You can avoid this easily. Check out @Quentin  's links above. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php
 session_start();
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","hi","hello");
 mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);
 $check_table=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$row[studentid]'.'to'.'$_GET[id]' ");
 if($check_table!=FALSE)
 {
 $asd="no suggestion";
 echo $asd;
 }
 else
 {
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE email='$_SESSION[user_name]'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$create_table="CREATE TABLE '$row[studentid]'.'to'.'$_GET[id]' (post_number int not  null 
 auto_increment,primary key(post_number),data text(20000))";
 $result=mysql_query($create_table,$con);
 }

 ?>
```